# Firefox addon: Connecting to SQLite database located in the addon's "data" folder

Tags: firefox-addon, sqlite

I am writing my first firefox add-ons using the addon-sdk.

The purpose of this add-on is to

- get data from a specific page,
- use this data to query the SQLite database built in the add-on,
- append the results of the queries in the specific page.

I have created my SQLite database with sqlite3 and stored it as myDB.db in the "data" folder or the add-on.

But when I try to open my database it does not work.

I tried like this without any success:

```
// Import the needed modules
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

// Open SQLite database
let file = FileUtils.getFile(self.data, ['myDB.db']);
let mDBConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file); // Will also create the file if it does not exist
```

I changed the location previously set to "ProfD" in the Mozilla storage documentation because the database is not there (or should I copy it there?).

Please tell me if I should proceed differently. I thought about SQLite because there are going to be a few queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wladimir Palant's accepted answer of ["How to initialize SQLite file for Firefox add-on?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986740/how-to-initialize-sqlite-file-for-firefox-add-on)

> As of Add-on SDK 1.5, extensions are no longer uncompressed upon
>   installation - they stay as packed XPI files on disk (which is good
>   for performance). SQLite needs a physical file however, not something
>   inside an archive.

You should use the ProfD folder to store your file. This also means that whatever data is stored in your db, remains there during upgrade or retro installation

Comment: But then I don't understand how can I store this DB in ProfD if I cannot retrieve it in my addon script?

Comment: Have you tried using ProfD? Did you encounter any error? If so what was it?

Comment: A sidenote, addons can be uncompressed on installation, but not advisable for performance reasons. Using ProfD is a much better solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests#unpack

Comment: It is also not advisable to store data in your unpacked extension directory, as the directory incl. your data will be deleted upon add-on uninstall *and* upon (automatic) add-on upgrades/downgrades.

Comment: By digging a bit with Wladimir Palant's answer, It seems like the a way to do that, was to create the DB and to populate it with the data from the DB that I already have.